# Angular interpolate error when setting source of base64 media

Tags: angularjs

so I have something like this:

```
<audio ng-switch-when="audio" controls ng-show="messageContent.retrieved"><source ng-src="{{messageContent.source}}"/></audio>
```

and this is where message content is defined:

```
messageLog.messages[i].messageContent[j].source = "data:audio/mp3;base64," + audioSource;
```

where audioSource is a base64 string. Compiling this in the html gives me this error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{messageContent.source}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with base64 video, only when I disable $sce completely it's working... I hope someone will come up with a valid solution for this

Answer (score 0):

try changing from

> messageLog.messages[i].messageContent[j].source = "data:audio/mp3;base64," + audioSource;

to

```
messageLog.messages[i].messageContent.source = "data:audio/mp3;base64," + audioSource;
```